# PDO insert and update stetement with if PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

my queries are :

```
   $select_userid_query = execute_pdo_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "'");

   if ($select_userid_query == 0){

    execute_pdo_query("INSERT INTO user_status
    (user_id,last_activity_time) VALUES
    ((SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "'),NOW())"
     , array($user_id, $last_activity_time));

   }
    else{
        execute_pdo_query("UPDATE user_status SET user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username='" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "'),last_activity_time= NOW()", array($user_id, $last_activity_time));
        }
```

i want to verify if there is a record in the database and if not insert and if there's just update the time of that with the new `NOW()`

any ideas where's my error in the syntax?

Comment: Why are you using PDO if you are not using the thing its build for, sql injection protecting. Dont put variables in the string when creating a PDO query. Instead give the variables as parameters, please look into it, as for your "error in the syntax" can you show us the error aswell?

Comment: no error, just not working, and please if you have some valid code for sql injection just post it.

Comment: Well i don't have a solution to your problem so usually people on this site only rage when you post 'suggestions' as answers. so here's how I use PDO http://pastebin.com/2XXtD3Tk I hope it helps. as for your error. I see some answers poping up i hope they can solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this you can use this single query if you have a `user_id` as unique:

```
INSERT INTO user_status
(
 user_id, last_activity_time
)
(
    SELECT user_id, NOW()
    FROM users
    WHERE username='" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "'"
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_activity_time = NOW();
```

Comment: you mean `execute_pdo_query("your_code"array($user_id, $last_activity_time));` ?

Comment: Good to see some diversity between answers! /s

Answer (score 2):

If `user_id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` you can use something this:

```
INSERT INTO ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_activity_time=NOW()
```